# In RSA, given public key $(n,e)$ and $d^e\bmod n$, can we factor $n$?

Tags: rsa

Given an RSA public key $(n,e)$ and the textbook-RSA encryption $c$ of a valid matching private exponent $d$, computed as $c\gets d^e\bmod n$:  **can we factor $n$ ?**

Assume $n,e,d$ are per [PKCS#1v2.2](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=6). If that helps, additionally assume any common (or not overly unlikely) condition helping towards a solution, e.g.:

1. $n$ product of two large primes $p$ and $q$
2. $d=e^{-1}\bmod\varphi(n)$ where $\varphi$ is the [Euler totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)
3. $d=e^{-1}\bmod\lambda(n)$ where $\lambda$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function)
4. $e$ small, perhaps just $e=3$
5. $e$ prime
6. $\gcd(p-1,q-1)=2$
7. $q<p<2q$

---

Motivation is this [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/82033/555), which I could only partially answer.

Problem is, textbook RSA encryption is conjectured secure for random secret plaintext. *Random secret* implies *independent of the key*, except for public modulus magnitude. *Independent of the key* is not met when encrypting $d$. As rightly pointed [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/82048/55), we are in unsafe territory. And for some plaintexts dependent on the private key, that would be totally unsafe. Example: if we reveal the encryption of $p$, that is $c'\gets p^e\bmod n$, we can decipher that as $p\gets \gcd(c',n)$. Other examples: revealing the encryption of $9\,q$ or of $d^d\bmod n$ breaks the security.

Comment: @kelalaka: $q<p<2q$ is a quantitative way to state that $p$ and $q$ are about the same size, which is often recommended. In some contexts involving RSA moduli, it simplifies things slightly (see e.g. last paragraph of [key generation in Paillier cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Paillier_cryptosystem&oldid=967933023#Key_generation)). It also specifies that $q$ is the smaller of the two. I could have written the stronger and common condition $2^{k-1/2}<q<p<2^{k}$, which insures $n$ is exactly $2\,k$ bits.

Comment: i.e. having $c = m^{e}\pmod{n}$ can we find $m$? Can't see any reason that we can find $n$ or even the message $m$. I can't see why is more interesting if we encrypt the secret key $d$.

Comment: @111: See new paragraph at end of question. Also, notice that $n$ is a given.

Comment: OK. thanks. see your point better now. Although, a second thought... you can't use $p$ as message since is not in the message space, ${\mathbb{Z}}_n^{*}.$

Comment: @111: yes you can encipher $p$, if $p\ne q$. Under that condition, RSA encryption/decryption works for all messages in $\Bbb Z_n$, with the usual formulas. We have several Q/A on that theme, see e.g. [this one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1004/555)

Comment: ok...although very artificial example (is there any such implementation of RSA?)

Comment: @111: encrypting $d$ or $p$ is indeed artificial. But implementations of RSA working in $\Bbb Z_n$ are the norm. Every implementation of encryption does. I can't name any implementation of decryption that does not.

Comment: Say for $e=3$ (using points 2,4,6), it seems you can compute something like $(-8ce^e - 27) \equiv(p-3)^3 + (q-3)^3 \pmod{n}$. Looks nice but does not sound usable.

Comment: *point 3 instead of 2

Comment: It is pretty amusing that in this case $-6 \equiv (p+q-3) / d \pmod{n}$. I would never guess that something like the quantity on the right is publicly computable.

Comment: Also note that $(p+q-3)^3 \equiv (p-3)^3+(q-3)^3 +27\pmod N$ is now known as well. Considering that $p+q-3$ is just the same order of magnitude as $\sqrt{N}$ (and knowing it is of course sufficient for factoring $N$) this seems pretty sub-optimal - however not quite the $N^{1/3}$ that something like Coppersmith's method would need to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

We can compute the amount of $E=e^{e-1} mod(n)$ then compute $C=c^E=(d^e)^{e^{e-1}}=d^{e^e} mod(n)$. Now we can compute the secret key $d$ as below:

$C^c=(d^{e^e})^{d^e} mod(n)=d^{e^e.d^e}=d^{(e.d)^e}=d^{1^e}=d \mod(n)$

Comment: Nice try, but that does not work. Counterexample: $e=3$, $p=5$, $q=11$, $n=55$, $\lambda(n)=\text{lcm}(p-1,q-1)=20$, $d=e^{-1}\bmod\lambda(n)=7$, $c=d^e\bmod n=13$, $E=e^{e-1}=9$, $C=c^E\bmod n=28$, $d'=C^c\bmod n=18$, $d'\not\equiv d\bmod\lambda(n)$. The error in the proof puzzled me for some time, it's in the step reading $C^c=(d^{e^e})^{d^e}$. That really means $C^c\equiv(d^{(e^e)})^{(d^e)}\bmod n$, and that's wrong, because $c$ is defined as $c=d^e\bmod n$, not $c=d^e$ or $c=d^e\bmod\lambda(n)$.

Comment: I think that, the amount of $d$, according to the RSA definition, should equal to $d=e^{-1}\ \bmod(\varphi(n))=27$. Because $\varphi(n)=40$ in your example.

Comment: Depends on what RSA, and it does not fix the answer. In the [original RSA article](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf), it is used $e=d^{-1}\bmodφ(n)$, which became $d=e^{-1}\bmodφ(n)$. In [PKCS#1v2.2](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=6) of the question, it is is allowed any  $d∈[1,n)$ with $e\,d\bmodλ(n)=1$, which allows $d=e^{-1}\bmod\varphi(n)$. In [FIPS-186](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf) it is required $d=e^{-1}\bmodλ(n)$, which often does not.